# How do I keep music playing when I switch apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, music, music.app

When I'm listening to music on my iOS device and open certain apps like games, the music stops. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: One possibility is your phone is old and is running short on memory. As a result if your foreground app requests for a lot of memory then the background app gets killed.

Comment: @user3528438 iPhone 13 Pro

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Music should keep playing when switching apps, unless the app you've switched to tries to take custody of media playback itself.

iOS gives priority to the foreground app for media playback, so other playback stops.

It's up to the app developer of the app you're switching to when playback stops to not code their app to stop background playback of other apps.

Comment: That's an insane UX.

Comment: @orome It's an understandable UX when you consider that at least on iOS you have exactly one volume control for media (ignoring that ringer/notification is a separate thing).

Comment: It is also up to the foreground app to determine _how_ it uses the audio output. There is a mode that allows mixing with other audio output, or reducing the volume of other audio output instead of turning it off. If that mode is used then an app could for example play an audio book while music is playing in the background. And it depends on where you output the music. I can play music on my speakers, and that will continue playing when the phone rings or the alarm goes off.

Comment: Also consider: playing music through Music.app, then switching over to Spotify to play different music; should both songs keep playing at the same time until you pause Music.app playback? Or opening a video in the YouTube app while music is playing: should the music keep playing in the background while you're watching the video?

Comment: @ItaiFerber OP: "certain apps like games", in fact in my case games where all sound had been turned off.

Comment: @orome Sure, but iOS doesn't distinguish between whether an app is a game, or a music player, or otherwise — so the behavior is consistent across all apps: the app in the foreground can decide what to do with playing audio. It could choose to pause all other audio, or let it continue playing in the background, or a mix of both.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Exactly. Like I said, terrible UX.

Comment: @orome Agree to disagree, I guess. As a user, I _value_ the consistent behavior across all apps, and not _having_ to manage audio across individual apps like I would otherwise. The point of my original comment is that if apps _couldn't_ control audio from other apps, many really common day-to-day interactions with audio would feel really needlessly annoying to me (and I suspect many others).